# Dropdown on each question specifying version

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, version-tags

I'm aware this has been asked before but I have a different suggestion. I don't believe that tagging is the answer to the version of SharePoint question. Why don't we simply have a dropdown checkbox list which allows the user to specify the version of SharePoint in question. 
Something like:

**- SharePoint 2007**

- WSS
- MOSS
- **SharePoint 2010**
- SharePoint Foundation
- SharePoint Enterprise
- SharePoint Online (Office 365)

etc.....

Comment: What if the user only knows the year and not the setup?

Comment: Or what if it's multiple versions affected?

Comment: @RJCuthbertson lets make it a Checkbox list then.

Comment: @Enilorac, Anyone posting a SharePoint question on StackExchange that doesn't know the version, should not be posting unfortunately. They should go and read up on SharePoint first. Anyways, we can also have a "Unknown" option.

Comment: @Fox Don't you think that's (for want of a better word) a bit elitist? It has already been decided that it's okay to ask "basic" or easily Google-able questions so I think it's unfair to exclude people who are new to SP or have limited priveledges just for not knowing about the SP environment that they haven't created

Comment: @Enilorac. Ok, maybe it is elitist. Do you have any idea though on how to fix the problem?

Comment: @Fox - correct me if I am wrong. You actual idea is to have version infos *separate* from the other tags, right?

Comment: @SPArchaeologist. Not neccessarily. I just want people to be forced to choose at least one of the tags: 2007,2010,2013 and optionally the version (Foundation,Server etc). Currently when answering, I have to first try and figure out what version the poster is referring to.

Comment: @Fox, ok then your idea is somehow different from mine. I will try to elaborate an answer then.

Comment: @Fox What do you define as "the problem"? If a question applies to multiple versions then it may get buried if the asker doesn't realise and only selects their version

Comment: Hi @Enilorac. It could be a checkboxlist allowing the user to select multiple versions.

Comment: @Fox You are assuming the user would know that it affects other versions, they may only know about their own setup

Comment: Look, you guys can keep asking my questions all day long but I'm sure you all know when i'm asking here. It's simple. When a user posts a question, they should at least be reminded to specify which version of SharePoint the are referring to. There are only a few, 2003, 2007, 2010, 2013. I don't even neccessarily care about the product version (Foundation, Server etc.), but as long as I know that it's either 2003,2007,2010,2013... That makes it much easier for me to answer the question.

Answer (score 2):

Check boxes are going to act just like tags and be just as useless. Years and versions are too broad to properly tag a question.

If I pose a question about WCM and tag it sharepoint enterprise, that does nothing for the visibility of the question. If I tag it what it is, WCM, then it immediately becomes apparent what the question is about.

Years and versions are important in the context of the question but are not a good basis for tagging the question.

Comment: I get your point Eric. But Fox actually seems to propose something different imho. As I read it, he wants to keep the existing tags infrastructure but move the version info to a different field. That would mean that you would still need to use a not-version tag for the question.

Comment: Then most questions are going to likely be tagged with a year and a platform and nothing else to be useful. As it stands, people don't tag properly, converting to this would be even worse. Year/version should be included in the question if it is necessary for the context of the proposed answers.